# How to check cron logs in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I went to `/var/log/cron` but this file is empty.

How to check if crontab is enabled or is running properly or not in ubuntu

thanks

Comment: This same question answered on below link
[answer from another trail](https://askubuntu.com/questions/624701/where-are-cron-logs-stored-on-ubuntu-14-04/1384537#1384537)
https://askubuntu.com/questions/624701/where-are-cron-logs-stored-on-ubuntu-14-04/1384537#1384537

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you want to know if it's running you can do something like `sudo systemctl status cron` or `ps aux | grep cron`.

If you want to know if your cron jobs are running, check `/var/log/syslog` with the process name cron.  For example:

```
Apr 26 21:17:01 example CRON[18055]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

Comment: Thanks buddy , i searc hed internet and they were sying the log file is /var/log/cron or cron.log , what is that file for

Comment: It all depends on how syslog is configured.  Some distributions/Unix will split everything out, other dump just about everything into one file.

Comment: Just for the record: Any `systemctl` attempts will not work in (unprivileged) docker containers. Try the answer from Sean then.

Answer (score 99):

1. modify `rsyslog` config: open `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`,remove `#` before `cron.*`
2. restart rsyslog service: `sudo service rsyslog restart`
3. restart cron service: `service cron restart`

now you can check cron log from file `/var/log/cron.log`

Comment: This is great. Saves searching through the syslog

Comment: Best answer so far.

Comment: Check `/etc/rsyslog.conf` if you're on an older system or if there's nothing in `/etc/rsyslog.d`

Comment: @Sean We can also restart the Cron service via `sudo service cron restart` apart from that your answer worked liked a Charm!!

Comment: This worked for me, but I additionally had to install `apt install rsyslog -y` first. Then there was no file in `rsyslog.d` as Wimateeka mentioned, but I modified `rsyslog.conf` directly.

Answer (score 26):

By default the cron log in Ubuntu is located at `/var/log/syslog`. Use the below command to check the cron entries in this file.

```
grep cron /var/log/syslog
```

Comment: Case insensitive search yields more comprehensive results.
`grep -i cron /var/log/syslog`

Answer (score 16):

New information for 2020:
cron is now a systemctl service, so you can have the logs of cron / anacron with:

`journalctl -u cron.service`

if you did install anacron, it is the same with:

`journalctl -u anacron.service`

(anacron is for desktop, when your computer is not garanteed to be always on. It enforce that even if your computer is down at 5'00, daily jobs are run when the computer has started up).

Comment: journalctl -u cron.service
No journal files were found.<- -on Ubuntu 20.04 WSL2

Comment: @relipse: I did try again, and it did work. Perhaps something is missing in your setup or in my explanation. If you find out, please complete this answer