# How to trace cron actions?

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I know that there are some cron jobs (run every minute) scheduled in my Ubuntu.

How do I track what's running them, 
when the cron files (`sudo su; crontab -e`) are empty?

Comment: answer from question trail
[answer from question trail](https://askubuntu.com/questions/624701/where-are-cron-logs-stored-on-ubuntu-14-04/1384537#1384537)
https://askubuntu.com/questions/624701/where-are-cron-logs-stored-on-ubuntu-14-04/1384537#1384537

Answer (score 4):

Send the `cron.*` syslog facility to its own file, see [How to check cron logs in Ubuntu](https://serverfault.com/q/136461/241174).  Review syslog crontab lines for edits, and the CRON lines for jobs run.

Review the crontab spool for users, the system wide crontab, and the .d directory.

```
/var/spool/cron
/etc/crontab
/etc/cron.d
```

The rest of the cron directories contain just scripts to run on the specified interval. These won't contain something run every minute.

```
/etc/cron.hourly
/etc/cron.monthly
/etc/cron.weekly
/etc/cron.daily
```

Answer (score 2):

Linux allow administrator to check all cron jobs running on the server, since you are running Ubuntu you need to go to `/var/spool/cron/crontabs` then `grep` all configured cron to see what job is running every minute `grep -r "*/1" *`.

Also you need to check if there is a user running a cron job that contains a repetitive condition.

Comment: The slash notation in `*/1` is not necessary,  `*` in the first column of a crontab runs every minute of the hour.

Answer (score 0):

**#to check all job run timeline**

```
cat /var/log/syslog | grep CRON
```

**#to check each job full log**

```
cd /var/mail/

ll
-rw-rw----  1 ubuntu mail 9342 Dec 31 07:35 ubuntu

less ubuntu
```

**#in the above file you can find the whole log**

just shift + g so you can see all new logs text

**#to check live file / log update**

```
tail -f /var/mail/ubuntu
```